# domdocument get content within a paragraph, not hyperlink

Tags: php, domdocument

I'm using DOMDocument to iterate through HTML to get the content within a `<p>` tag. But at the same time I don't wanna get anything from `href`, `div` and `span` info within the `<p>` tag. How should I proceed from the code below:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($data);
$pas = $domDoc->getElementsByTagName("p");
foreach ($pas as $pa)
    $pa->textContent
```

Can I further do a DOMDocument `getElementsByTagName()`  for div, span, href from `$pas`? Or will I need to do a regular expression?

Comment: Just for clarification, you want to skip content of `div`, `span` and `a` tags that are in `p` tag?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. The question editor accepts some HTML tags to provide formatting so when you need to insert literal tags you need to use the `{}` toolbar button. I've fixed it for you this time. There's a preview panel below the edit box where you can see what your question will look like. Additionally, you can get uppercase letters with your keyboard's `Shift` key.

Comment: Hi alvarco, tks for helping.  Hmm i actually did the html formatting. Mayb it got removed after i edited in mobile

Answer (score 1):

You can use like this

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($data);
$rootElement = $document->documentElement;//selecting document root

$pTags = $rootElement->getElementsByTagName("p");//selecting all p tags from DOM
$pas = $pTags->item(0);// selecting first p tag

foreach ($pas as $pa) {
    if($pa->nodeName == 'div' || $pa->nodeName == 'span' || $pa->nodeName == 'a')
    continue;
    // do everything else here
}
```

Comment: hi i just tried. its not working. im trying to do a workaround, to iterate through the childnodes but its not helping either. basically its returning string in <a href="">string</a> which i dont need

Comment: it should work, post your html with question so that I can test it

Comment: hey im thinking of using domxpath instead. im currently struggling on how to query for containing only <img>, <p> and <span>